# Is that the gas price actually affects the transaction time on the Ropsten testnet

Tags: transactions, gas, ropsten

I know that If the gas price is high enough, the transaction will be executed sooner since miners will execute transactions with the highest gas price first.

does this rule really apply in the Ropsten testnet, do miners take a fee to mine blocks in such testnet?

In fact, I made the same transaction using a gas price = 0.000000001 (1 Gwei)and gas price = 0.00000002(20 Gwei) and I did not notice a difference in the execution time. In the opposite, sometimes the transaction with 20Gwei take much more time to be executed

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The blocks tend to be somewhat empty. For example [this recent block](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/3717193) used < 10% of the gas limit. Because there are few transactions on Ropsten, every transaction tends to get mined in the next block.

Answer (score 0):

I do feel that the gas price does play the same role on Ropsten as that on the Mainnet. From my experience, even in ropsten, the transactions with higher gas price are executed faster.